# CSS dropdown menu displays behind video

Tags: css, navigation, wmv

I have a css drop down menu, so that when you hover over a menu item a submenu drops down.  I am also displaying a .wmv video on the page.  However when the sub menu drops down, it displays behind the video.  I've read where anything in the object tag automatically gets the maximum z-index, so setting the z-index doesn't fix the issue.  I haven't been able to find any solutions or work arounds.  Is there a work around or some way to fix this so that the drop down menu displays in front of the video?  This seems to be happening in IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you have to set the background of the player object to be transparent. Like this:

```
<object ... >

   <param name="filename" value="http://yourdomain/yourmovie.wmv">
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent">

   <!-- other params -->

   <embed ... wmode="transparent"></embed>
</object>
```

Hope it helps. I don't remember exactly all the params and so on, but it should do the trick.

Comment: I believe this works for flash videos, but I couldn't get it to work for wmv.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with zerolab. If wmode transparent doesn't do the trick though, try:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be ways to achieve that by css and embedded video player's options but as a quick solution check this one as a jquery help.

> http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe

Hope it helps, Sinan.